# Trying to make a live data grapher with CImg library (C++)

Tags: c++, cimg

I'm new to CImg. Not sure if there's already a live data plotter in the library but I thought I'd go ahead and make one myself. If what I'm looking for already exists in the library please point me to the function. otherwise, here is my super inefficient code that I'm hoping you can help me with~

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CImg.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>

using namespace cimg_library;

int main()
{
    CImg<unsigned char> plot(400, 320, 1, 3, 0);
    CImgDisplay graph(plot, "f(x)");

    clock();
    const unsigned char red[] =  {255, 0, 0};

    float* G = new float[plot.width()];      //define an array holding the values that are to be displayed on the graph

    while (1){
        G[0] = ((plot.height()/4) * sin(clock() / 1000.0)) + plot.height()/2;         // new f(t) value
        for (int i = 1; i <= plot.width() - 1; i++){
            G[plot.width() - i] = G[plot.width() - i - 1];  //basically shift all the array values to current address+1
            plot.draw_point(plot.width() - 3*i, G[i-1], red, 1).display(graph);
            }
        plot.fill(0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**problems**
the grapher traverses right to left soo slowly.. and I'm not sure how to make a smooth curve hence I went with points.. how do you make a smooth curve?

Answer (score 0):

There is already something for you in the library, method `CImg<T>::draw_graph()`, as (brielfy) explained here : 
http://cimg.eu/reference/structcimg__library_1_1CImg.html#a2e629aadedc4518001f00333f25bfec8

There are few examples provided with the library that use this method, see files `examples/tutorial.cpp` and `examples/plotter1d.cpp`.